# Selected language information using custom labels in visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is when we select language from drop down that language related information should appear.I tried this way its not getting my requirement..

```
<apex:page controller="pages" language="{!selected}">
<apex:form >
<div >
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:actionFunction name="RefreshRole" rerender="sam" status="checkboxtc">
<apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selected}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
Language:<apex:selectList id="subroleList" value="{!selected}" onchange="RefreshRole(this.value)" size="1" >
<apex:selectOption itemLabel="----------------" itemValue="none"></apex:selectOption>
<apex:selectOption itemLabel="nl" itemValue="nl"></apex:selectOption>
<apex:selectOption itemLabel="de" itemValue="de"></apex:selectOption>       
</apex:selectList>         
</apex:actionRegion>
 <div class="item-label" id="sam">{!$Label.sample}</div> 
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I would recommend to make it URL param, and on selection -- just redirect to page with language param. if that still fill your requirements

Comment: can you provide any reference site please?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AqtoIAC

Comment: It is different my requirement different can you please help on when we select language in dropdown how it will add in url...

Comment: generate the url in your controller. There you have the 'selected' variable.

Answer (score 0):

Rerender should contain Salesforce Id for Apex Component like

You can't put DOM element id in Rerender.

I mean you may put but it wouldn't work unless that DOM element Id matches some Apex Component Id, which should be the parent element for the stuff you want to rerender